# jQuery dataTables , how to send input csv values and save in the csv file in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv, datatables

I have the csv file , which i populated in the datatables...using the php script ...

```
SSW MGWNAME BOARDNO FRAMENO SLOTNO  PORTNO  E1  TID
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   0   2048-2079
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   1   2080-2111
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   2   2112-2143
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   3   2144-2175
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   4   2176-2207
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   5   2208-2239
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   6   2240-2271
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   7   2272-2303
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   8   2304-2335
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   9   2336-2367
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   10  2368-2399
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   11  2400-2431
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   12  2432-2463
DLHUGC01    NEHMGW01    0   1   2   0   13  2464-2495
```

Now the above csv file is pupulating in the table format..using the datatables,

This is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">

    <title>DataTables example - Form inputs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/syntax/shCore.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/demo.css">
    <style type="text/css" class="init">

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/syntax/shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">


$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('button').click( function() {
        var data = table.$('input, select').serialize();
        alert(
            "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+
            data.substr( 0, 120 )+'...'
        );
        return false;
    } );
} );


    </script>
</head>

<body class="dt-example">

            <button type="submit">Submit form</button>

            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                        <tr> 
                           <th>SSW</th> 
                            <th>MGWNAME</th>
                            <th>BOARDNO</th>
                            <th>FRAMENO</th> 
                            <th>SLOTNO</th>
                            <th>PORTNO</th>
                            <th>E1</th>
                            <th>TID</th> 
                            <th>TG</th>
                            <th>CIC</th>
                            <th>OPC</th>
                            <th>DPC</th>
                            <th>SLC</th> 
                            <th>NLDTRAILID</th> 
                            <th>CircleTRAILID</th>
                            <th>USERLABEL</th>
                            <th>MGW-NLDHandoverDetails</th>
                            <th>NA</th>
                            <th>NA</th> 
                            <th>NA</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <?php

                            $f = fopen("LDHUAWEI.csv", "r");

                            while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
                            {
                                    echo "<tr id='tr_data'>";
                                    $i=1;
                                        foreach ($line as $cell)
                                        {   

                                                echo "<td><input type='text' id='row-".$i."-age' name='row-".$i."-age'  value=".$cell."></td>";                                                 
                                            $i++;
                                        }

                                    echo "</tr>\n";
                            }

                            fclose($f);
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have echoed with input text in the loop and in the value the values are passing ..now the user edit and send submit from button...it has to change in the csv file ...

the particular values in the table should write in the csv file .....getting the entire row of the edited value and write in csv file...

thanks..

Comment: What did you try to update the file?

Comment: The values from the input box, if the user edits the particular row...than the input values edit in the csv file..